# How to combine a loop of Axios calls with an await-ed function?

Tags: vue.js, async-await, axios

That's a tricky one I guess. I'm prompting user for a word which I validate with an `Axios` API call. Once validation clears, the main loop of my game - hangman - starts with a wait between each move (hence the use of `await`).

Problem: in current version, the main game loop (starting after *"once validation clears, game starts below"* comment) must starts **after** validation, when in fact it starts at the same time which messes everything up.

And I can't put my main loop inside the `then()` part of my `Axios` call because in that case the await-ed function call ceases to work.

Any idea to get out of this mess?

```js
    async startGameComputerGuesser () {
      var wordIsValidated = false
      const vm = this
      const dispatcher = {
        execute: function () {
          const wordApiBaseUrl = 'https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/sd4/xml'
          wordToGuess = prompt('Enter a word:').toLowerCase()
          const dispatcher = this
          vm.axios.get(`${wordApiBaseUrl}/${wordToGuess}?key=${wordApiKey}`).then(res => {
            if (!res.data.includes('def')) {
              dispatcher.execute()
            } else {
              wordIsValidated = true
            }
          })
        }
      }
      dispatcher.execute()

      // once validation clears, game starts below
      if (wordIsValidated) {
        while (!this.$store.state.gameIsOver) {
          await this.resolveAfter2Seconds()
          // main loop of the game goes here
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `await` inside the `execute` and return true/false then use `while` to check that condition like below

```
async startGameComputerGuesser() {
  let wordIsValidated = false;
  const vm = this;
  const dispatcher = {
    async execute() {
      const wordApiBaseUrl = 'https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/sd4/xml'
      const wordToGuess = prompt('Enter a word:').toLowerCase();
      const res = await vm.axios.get(`${wordApiBaseUrl}/${wordToGuess}?key=${wordApiKey}`);
      return res.data.includes('def');
    }
  }

  // validation
  while (!wordIsValidated) {
    wordIsValidated = await dispatcher.execute();
  }

  // game starts below
  while (!this.$store.state.gameIsOver) {
    await this.resolveAfter2Seconds()
    // main loop of the game goes here
  }
}
```

Example code:

```js
const startGameComputerGuesser = async function() {
  let wordIsValidated = false;
  
  const dispatcher = {
    async execute() {
      const res = await new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)), 500));
      console.log(res);
      return res == 6;
    }
  }

  // validation
  while (!wordIsValidated) {
    wordIsValidated = await dispatcher.execute();
  }
  
  // once validation clears, game starts below
  console.log('started');
}

startGameComputerGuesser();
```